# Does p (dimensionality) include the dependent variable?

Tags: dependent-variable

Let us say I have a dat set of the following:

1. Weight
2. Height
3. Body Fat Index

is the dimensionality of the data 2 or 3 or does it depend if I'm trying to do say K-means clustering vs say linear regression where Weight is the dependent variable?

Comment: Could you explain why quantifying the "dimensionality" might matter in your situation?

Comment: @whuber just trying to understand the definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimensionality depends on the problem.

In linear regression, assuming you are trying to model the relationship between
weight,height and Body Fat Index, with Body Fat Index as the dependent variable
the dimensionality is 2.

In a clustering problem the dimensionality becomes 3.